# Are there some a, b such that max(a, b) != max(b, a)?

Tags: python, python-3.x

In python 3.x, are there some `a`, `b` such that `max(a, b) != max(b, a)`?

`a` and `b` should be of a built-in python type and do not contain any conversion.

The type of `a` and `b` can be:
num, float, bool, list, tuple ...

Example:

```py
a = 1 # Correct
a = [1, 2] # Correct
a = float('nan') # Wrong
```

Comment: your question is not clear

Comment: I don't think there is any... `max` is a built-in function that takes an [iterable](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-iterable) object as input. So, `a,b` is the same as `b,a` hence `max(a,b)` must equal `max(b,a)`

Comment: This is a good question but you should edit it and explain it more

Comment: Your edit only makes sense in the context of your comment below the most up voted answer.  There and here, you fail to argue that `float('nan')` is not a built-in type.  I would assume "built-in type" would mean anything you can create without having to create a new `class`.

Comment: If you want to exclude `float('nan')`, then why?  To be clear, you're allowed to ask a question in which you exclude something like `float('nan')` if you want; that's not the problem.  The problem's just that no one's sure what you're trying to ask.

Comment: In the recent edit, you've further specified that neither `a` nor `b` can involve a "_conversion_"; what do you mean by that?  I mean, I get the sense that you want the answer to be `max(a, b) == max(b, a)`, and you're wanting to reduce the problem statement down to the point where this equality would be true.  Is this a correct interpretation of what you're going for?  If so, you might want to ask a different question about what constraints you can impose on `a` and `b` such that `max(a, b) == max(b, a)` must be true.

Answer (score 17):

This satisfies all criteria:

```
>>> max(1.0, float("nan"))
1.0

>>> max(float("nan"), 1.0)
nan
```

This is because any comparisons other than `!=` or `is` with `float("nan")` always return false.

More generally, we can have `max(a, b) != max(b, a)` when the type(s) of `a, b` do not provide a total order. As Daniel Mesejo points out, sets have this property as well. For sets `<` means 'strict subset', but with `{1, 2}` and `{3, 4}` neither is a strict subset of the other, so:

```
>>> max({1, 2}, {3, 4})
{1, 2}

>>> max({3, 4}, {1, 2})
{3, 4}
```

This one technically doesn't have `max(a, b) != max(b, a)` because `1 == True`, but there's still an observable difference:

```
>>> max(True, 1)
True

>>> max(1, True)
1
```

Comment: WOW... why is that??

Comment: The second example also works for all equal, but not identical strings or collections, where `not max(a, b) is max(b, a)`

Comment: In first case, b = float("nan") which is not a built-in type. They can only be num, float, str, list, tuple ...,etc.

Comment: @stackFF4 if `float("nan")` is not built-in, than what is it? It is certainly built-in.

Comment: @stackFF4: `float('nan')` is a float. It says `float` right there, so I'm not sure what else you expected it to be. You can check it with `type` if you want.

Comment: @Anwarvic: Interestingly, it's not a python thing, it's actually how floats are implemented in hardware. NaN compares false with everything in almost every programming language.

Comment: `NaN` is an indefinite.  It shouldn't compare as `true` _or_ `false` to anything in an otherwise unqualified context, but rather throw an exception.  That it compares as `false`, including to itself, is a logical inconsistency.

Comment: @Nat: But nobody wants exceptions most of the time.  This `max` behaviour is an artifact of defining it differently from C `fmax` (which guarantees NaN propagation), instead as something like `a<b ? b : a` which always produces `a` when the comparison is false.  NaN is "unordered" wrt. any other number, so `a < NaN` is always false, and so is `NaN < b`

Comment: @MooingDuck: Yes, if you mean instructions like x86 SSE `maxsd` ([What is the instruction that gives branchless FP min and max on x86?](//stackoverflow.com/q/40196817)).  But C `fmin` and `fmax` aren't defined in terms of a simple ternary so do propagate NaN.  If you want that then use FP-aware min/max functions (which can't compile as efficiently in ahead-of-time compiled languages).

Answer (score 5):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.7/reference/expressions.html#value-comparisons), using `max` on sets produces undefined results:

> Accordingly, sets are not appropriate arguments for functions which
>   depend on total ordering (for example, min(), max(), and sorted()
>   produce undefined results given a list of sets as inputs).

Here is an example,

```
a = {1, 2}
b = {2, 3}
print(max(b, a) != max(a, b))
```

**Output**

```
True
```

Comment: It might be worth noting here that "undefined results" are probably saner in Python than in some other languages. No [nasal demons](http://catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html) are likely, and it probably won't even raise an exception. It just returns a mostly arbitrary value (for `min` and `max`) or ordering (for `sorted`).